# How to stop loading a form in constructor in C# form application

Tags: c#

I have 2 forms. I get the requested data to connect to database in Form1, send it to Form2, show Form2 and fill the datagridview in constructor of Form2 after connecting to database. Here I check if there is any rows in sdr (SqlDataReader). If not, what I want to do is stopping the Form2 to be loaded and turn back to Form1.

I tried **this.close()** but it doesn't work while executing the constructor of Form2.

```
if (!sdr.HasRows)
   {
      MessageBox.Show("No Data!", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
      this.Close();
   }
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Can you check your data before creating form2?

Comment: yeah I get requested data to connect to database and check if sdr (SqlDataReader) has rows or not. I didnt want to connect to database in form1.

Comment: so I can check but I dont want to.

Comment: I'm very curious to know why it is so important that the "constructor needs to be stopped" - can you elaborate a bit on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closing and in general loading of the data has not to be done inside `ctor` of the `Form`, but inside [Form.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load.aspx) event.

For example:

```
//Form2.cs 



 public class Form2 : Form
 {
    ..... 

    public override OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    { 
       ......
       if (!sdr.HasRows)
       {
          MessageBox.Show("No Data!", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
          this.Close();
        }
    }   


  }
```

Comment: so there is no way to stop in constructor ?

Comment: @MustafaTok: there is no **sence** of stoping constructor. Let him to construct the object, and when it's constructed close the window fomr the `OnLoad`. Or, if you don't want to construct object if the grid is empty, just add control inside `Form1` call, so if the grid is empty do not call `Form2` at all.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply do your check before showing the form? Form1 has the data necessary to make the decision.

```
if(!sdr.HasRows)
  //show error
else    
  //show form2.
```

Comment: yes I have the data, I connect to database in Form2, I didnt want to do this in Form1.

Comment: Then you might consider editing your question. As you stated: *I have 2 forms. I get the requested data in Form1
 *